# Chicken and Egg nightmare with Django mixin

Tags: python, django, mixins

I am upgrading a large Django-based app from Django 1.7 app to Django 2.2 and am having a lot of trouble with a permissions-related mixin.

```
   class PrincipalRoleRelation(models.Model):

    """A role given to a principal (user or group). If a content object is
    given this is a local role, i.e. the principal has this role only for this
    content object. Otherwise it is a global role, i.e. the principal has
    this role generally.

    user
        A user instance. Either a user xor a group needs to be given.

    group
        A group instance. Either a user xor a group needs to be given.

    role
        The role which is given to the principal for content.

    content
        The content object which gets the local role (optional).
    """

       :::

    user         = models.ForeignKey(User,        verbose_name=_(u"User"),         blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    group        = models.ForeignKey(Group,       verbose_name=_(u"Group"),        blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    role         = models.ForeignKey(Role,        verbose_name=_(u"Role"),                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)

       :::
```

However, this fails to load during app initialization because User, Group, and Role etc are also apps whose loading is in progress and "populate() is not re-entrant" (so Dango complains)

I tried to work round this by amending the above code to create a sort of "skeleton" class which does not attempt to reference any other apps, e.g. :

```
app_models_loaded = True

try:
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    User = get_user_model()
except:
    app_models_loaded = False

if app_models_loaded:

    from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

    user         = models.ForeignKey(User,        verbose_name=_(u"User"),         blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    group        = models.ForeignKey(Group,       verbose_name=_(u"Group"),        blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    role         = models.ForeignKey(Role,        verbose_name=_(u"Role"),                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
              :::
```

Then in manage.py I would define the full mixin class, called say PrincipalRoleRelation2 and overwrite the skeleton class via the code :

```
from django.contrib import admin

from permissions.models import PrincipalRoleRelation

if admin.site.is_registered(PrincipalRoleRelation):
    admin.site.unregister(PrincipalRoleRelation)

admin.site.register(PrincipalRoleRelation, PrincipalRoleRelation2)
```

However, although this almost seems to work, I am not seeing some of the PrincipalRoleRelation2 attributes, "role" for example, in what I hoped would be the re-mapped PrincipalRoleRelation class with all attributes present.

I feel I am digging myself into an ever deeper hole, and that the above approach is unsound and will never work properly. So any help would be very much appreciated!

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

edit: In response to schillingt's comment, the User class is defined as follows:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):  # , PermissionsMixin):
    """ Custom user model
        Currently just used by the tests for django-permissions

        All unique user fields required for a user
        NB: Fields that are customizable across multiple identities will be part of a Profile object
    """
    # Dont use PermissionsMixin since not using contrib.auth.models.Permissions
    # and not using authentication backend perms ... so its only relevant for groups
    # ... however it causes user.groups relations name clashes ..
    # But we are using the groups part with django-permissions:
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, verbose_name=_('groups'),
                                    blank=True, help_text=_('The groups this user belongs to. A user will '
                                                            'get all permissions granted to each of '
                                                            'his/her group.'),
                                    related_name="user_set", related_query_name="user")
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(_('superuser status'), default=False,
                                       help_text=_('Designates that this user has all permissions without '
                                                   'explicitly assigning them.'))

    username = models.EmailField(_('Email (Username)'), max_length=255, unique=True)
    # Make username an email and just dummy in email here so its clearer for user.email use cases
```

Comment: This seems like a circular reference problem which requires knowing which apps have dependencies on which other apps. Can you show us where that circular reference is?

Comment: Hi schillingt, I have included the definition of the "User" class (including cryptic comments) in the question text, and the other classes come from https://pypi.org/project/django-permissions/  in permissions/models.py. This did work in Django 1.7 Note that django-permissions is a pretty ancient package though, not updated for several years.

Comment: Oof. That's likely to be painful. You may want to start with forking that project and getting it up to date with Django 3.0, then come back to your own project.

Comment: I did fork it, but I'm far from expert with Django and wouldn't know where to start with any necessary updates. I was rather hoping it would still work, or at least fail only in obvious ways that I could easily locate and fix. As I said, my scheme _almost_ seems to work. It's just that my replacement mixin module doesn't seem to replace the "skeleton" version. Perhaps there is an alternative to using admin.site.register() ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the experience in this area to be able to help you quickly.  Maybe someone else will/can. I'd have to do a deep-dive into the project(s).

Answer (score 0):

As a solution for circular refferrence, django has an ability to specify ForeignKey (or any other relational field) with string refferrence to related model, instead of importing the actual class.

```
user = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This is imo the recommended way to define related fields.